# Xamarin.Forms: Custom Context Actions For Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Hi i have a list view in which i added ContextActions.

i need to change Text Size, color and alignment of menu item in context actions,
also i want to increase width of context action on which menu item is appearing?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <customControls:ExtendedViewCell SelectedBackgroundColor="Transparent" >
                    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <MenuItem Text="Call" />
                        <MenuItem Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" />
                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" 
                     Padding="4" Spacing="8">
                            <Label TextColor="OrangeRed" Text="{Binding Title}"     />
                            <Label TextColor="Blue" Text="{Binding Subtitle}  "/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </customControls:ExtendedViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

After you change the content of the cell, call ForceUpdateSize() 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.Cell.ForceUpdateSize?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: when I am pressing on cell menu item(call,delete button) is coming on top black bar I need to change color, width and positioning of menu item(call,delete) and I need to change color and width of navigation bar on which call and delete is appearing....